# c# Regex for address

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string from a csv file. I'm trying to remove the commas from values between quotes,
but only if it's not a number.

For instance, I have this string.

```
6/4/2020,11111,John,Doe,"111 st , city,State",city,st,11111,email@gmail.com,11111111111,11111111111,"$370,000.00","$500,000.00 ",blah blah blah,"$370,000.00 ",4.25%,stable,74.00%,Rate and Term,0.00%,$0.00 ,Good,No
```

The st address from above is

```
"111 st , city,State"
```

I can remove the commas between quotes with this regex

```
var regex = new Regex("\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
```

However, that also removes the commas in the numbers

```
"$370,000.00"
```

How can I remove the commas in the address, but ignore the number fields with a dollar sign $?

Here is an example code

```
    var test = $"6/4/2020,test,test,testJR,\"111 test DRIVE, city, st\",city,st,11111,test@gmail.com,11111,11111,\"$370,000.00 \",\"$500,000.00 \",Single Family Residence,\"$370,000.00 \",4.25%,Fixed,74.00%,Rate and Term,0.00%,$0.00 ,Good,No";
    var regex = new Regex("\\\"(.*?)\\\"");
    test = regex.Replace(test, m => m.Value.Replace(',', ' '));
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ZXirZQ/1 will find "Full match 23-46 ,"111 st , city,State","  adapt this for your own needs (if needed).

Comment: Try some CSV-parser

Comment: Maybe the regex `/\"\d+(\s?\w+\s?\,?)+\"/g`, see the sample - https://regexr.com/59qns

Comment: the cleanest solution: _store numbers as numbers_ and not as string ;)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Unfortunately, there is a lot going on in this code base and I would like to change as little as possible.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Ty, I have no control over that though.

Comment: @Luuk Thanks that will come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
var regex = new Regex(@"""\s*\$\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\s*""|(""[^""]*"")");
test = regex.Replace(test, m => m.Groups[1].Success ? 
    m.Groups[1].Value.Replace(',', ' ') : m.Value);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/zFXmRS)

**Details**

- `"\s*\$\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\s*"`:

  - `"\s*\$` - `"`, then 0+ whitespaces and then a `$` char
  - `\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?` - 1+ digits, then 0 or more occurrences of a comma and then 1+ digits, and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and 1+ digits
  - `\s*"`  - 0+ whitespaces and then `"`
- `|`  - or
- `("[^"]*")` - Capturing group 1:  `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then `"`.

The `m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value.Replace(',', ' ') : m.Value)` means that commas are replaced with spaces only if Capturing group 1 matched, else, the match is returned as is.

Comment: Fantastic! Is there a tool you used to generate the Regex?

Comment: @Train It is a simple regex, I wrote it manually. You may use regex101.com to write such a regex, test at regexstorm.net/tester to see if it works with .NET regex, and then test in code.